# Chrome dev tools see more precise timing for requests > 1 minute

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm doing some comparisons of network request timing. Chrome dev tools provides precision to the hundredths decimal place in seconds when the request is less than one minute, but only to the tenths decimal place in minutes for requests greater than one minute. Is there a way to get greater precision here?

[image: de]